# How to replace a node in DOM with a new one?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have some DOM element which I retrieve with `getElementById` method.

I need to replace this element with new html-element (i.e. I want to see correctly-rendered `<h1>hello</h1>` in the place where the old element were shown.

How can I do that? (p.s. jquery is not allowed).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.replaceChild) for DOM node replacement. There's an example in the link which show the replaceChild with parentNode combination.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very cautious about using innerHTML blindly. DOM manipulation methods such as createElement/appendChild/insertBefore/replaceChild etc.. are the more "correct" way to do DOM manipulation (naturally) but there are [some circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) where innerHTML is more appropriate and some where it causes Really Bad Things.

It's a bit of a religious war tbh.

Comment: Yes, I need some dom manipulations, but I've never done it yet. Will look for some examples.