# Replacing DIV content based on variable sent from another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get this JavaScript working:

I have an HTML email which links to this page which contains a variable in the link (index.html?content=email1). The JavaScript should replace the DIV content depending on what the variable for 'content' is.

```
<!-- ORIGINAL DIV -->
<div id="Email">

</div>


<!-- DIV replacement function -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
</script>

<!-- Email 1 Content -->
<script ="text/javascript">
var content = '<div class="test">Email 1 content</div>';

ReplaceContentInContainer('Email1',content);
}
</script>

<!-- Email 2 Content -->
<script ="text/javascript">
var content = '<div class="test">Email 2 content</div>';

ReplaceContentInContainer('Email2',content);
}
</script>
```

Any ideas what I've done wrong that is causing it not to work?

Comment: Where are the `id="Email1"` and `id="Email2"` elements?

Comment: I just added this to it:  

<!-- Email 1 Content -->
<script ="text/javascript">
var content = '<div id="Email1">Email 1 content</div>';

ReplaceContentInContainer('Email1',content);
}
</script>

<!-- Email 2 Content -->
<script ="text/javascript">
var content = '<div id="Email2">Email 2 content</div>';

ReplaceContentInContainer('Email2',content);
}
</script>

I think I knew what you meant but I'm quite new to JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than inserting the element as text into `innerHTML` create a DOM element, and append it  manually like so:

```
var obj = document.createElement("div");
obj.innerText = "Email 2 content";
obj.className = "test"

document.getElementById("email").appendChild(obj);
```

See this working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BE8Xa/1/

**EDIT**

Interesting reading to help you decide if you want to use `innerHTML` or `appendChild`:

["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode)

Comment: Thanks for the comments James. If I were to use your code, would I replace the code commented as <!-- DIV replacement function --> above?

From what I can see in your JSFiddle, 'Email 2 Content' is generated as the result... What I need to happen is have the result generated by the variable sent in the URL from the previous page (well an HTML email to be exact). thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ReplaceContentInContainer calls specify ID's which are not present, the only ID is Email and also, how are the two scripts called, if they are in the same apge like in the example the second (with a corrected ID) would always overwrite the first and also you declare the content variable twice which is not permitted, multiple script blocks in a page share the same global namespace so any global variables has to be named uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

David's on the money as to why your DOM script isn't working: there's only an 'Email' id out there, but you're referencing 'Email1' and 'Email2'.

As for grabbing the content parameter from the query string:

```
var content = (location.search.split(/&*content=/)[1] || '').split(/&/)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I just include this line of code within <!-- DIV replacement function --> ?

Comment: This way:

var contentStr = (location.search.split(/&*content=/)[1] || '').split(/&/)[0];

var content = '<div class="test">' + contentStr + '</div>';

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are putting a closing "}" after you call "ReplaceContentInContainer". I don't know if that is your complete problem but it would definitely cause the javascript not to parse correctly. Remove the closing "}".

With the closing "}", you are closing a block of code you never opened.

Comment: Thanks. Just took that off, it will certainly help getting this working :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, parse the query string data to find the desired content to show. To achieve this, add this function to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ParseQueryString() {
    var result = new Array();
    var strQS = window.location.href;
    var index = strQS.indexOf("?");
    if (index > 0) {
        var temp = strQS.split("?");
        var arrData = temp[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            temp = arrData[i].split("=");
            var key = temp[0];
            var value = temp.length > 0 ? temp[1] : "";
            result[key] = value;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
```

Second step, have all possible DIV elements in the page, initially hidden using `display: none;` CSS, like this:

```
<div id="Email1" style="display: none;">Email 1 Content</div>
<div id="Email2" style="display: none;">Email 2 Content</div>
...
```

Third and final step, in the page load (after all DIV elements are loaded including the placeholder) read the query string, and if `content` is given, put the contents of the desired DIV into the "main" div.. here is the required code:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var QS = ParseQueryString();
    var contentId = QS["content"];
    if (contentId) {
        var source = document.getElementById(contentId);
        if (source) {
            var target = document.getElementById("Email");
            target.innerHTML = source.innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `location.search` is a neater way to get the query string without having to go question mark hunting.

Comment: @David is this cross browser? I remember having hard times with it few years ago so since then I try to avoid using it.

Comment: I've never heard of a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Hacky but works...

```
<!-- ORIGINAL DIV -->
<div id="Email"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
var container = document.getElementById(id);
var txt = document.createTextNode(content); 
container.appendChild(txt);
}

window.onload = function() {
var args = document.location.search.substr(1, document.location.search.length).split('&');
var key_value = args[0].split('=');
ReplaceContentInContainer('Email', key_value[1]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: That's great Nick, it's displaying the variable on the page but I'd like it to display a specific DIV associated to the variable. 

e.g. If the variable is 'email1', it will display a div called 'email1'.

Maybe have div's hidden with CSS and when the variable is selected it displays it???

What do you think?

Comment: or build them dynamically, does the div have to have content of the argument in it? so if you got "?email1=foo" the email1 div would have 'foo' in it? it's probably easier dynamically if thats the case, if its just a set of options use css to display/hide it