# Same function repeatedly called resets the setTimeout inner function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

All,

I have a 'credit module' (similar to credit system in games), which when a user performs an action, creates an inner div with the cost to be added or substracted so user can see what the cost of the last action was.

Problem: Everything works fine as long as the function is called once, if the user performs multiple actions quickly, the setTimeout functions (which are suppose to animate & then delete the cost div) donot get executed. It seems the second instance of the function resets the setTimeout function of the first.

```
(function()
{

$("#press").on("click", function(){creditCost(50)});

function creditCost(x)
{
var eParent = document.getElementById("creditModule");
// following code creates the div with the cost
eParent.innerHTML += '<div class="cCCost"><p class="cCostNo"></p></div>';
var aCostNo = document.getElementsByClassName("cCostNo");
var eLatestCost = aCostNo[aCostNo.length - 1];
// following line assigns variable to above created div '.cCCost'
var eCCost = eLatestCost.parentNode;
// cost being assigned
eLatestCost.innerHTML = x;
$(eCCost).animate ({"left":"-=50px", "opacity":"1"}, 250, "swing");
// following code needs review... not executing if action is performed multiple times quickly
setTimeout(function()
{
    $(eCCost).animate ({"left":"+=50px", "opacity":"0"}, 250, "swing", function ()
    {
        $(eCCost).remove();
    })  
}, 1000);
}

})();
```

[jsfiddle, excuse the CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/ShCHD/1/)

Comment: Im trying to use as much js as possible as our web application is pretty heavy as it is & we are trying to rely on jquery only for onload events & bindings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eParent.innerHTML += '<div class="cCCost"><p class="cCostNo"></p></div>';
```

is the bad line. This resets the `innerHTML` of your element, recreating the whole DOM and destroying the elements which were referenced in the previous invocations - letting their timeouts fail. See ["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2305654/1048572) for details. Why don't you use jQuery when you have it available?

```
function creditCost(x) {
    var eParent = $("#creditModule");
    // Create a DOM node on the fly - without any innerHTML
    var eCCost = $('<div class="cCCost"><p class="cCostNo"></p></div>');

    eCCost.find("p").text(x); // don't set the HTML if you only want text

    eParent.append(eCCost); // don't throw over all the other children
    eCCost.animate ({"left":"-=50px", "opacity":"1"}, 250, "swing")
          .delay(1000) // of course the setTimeout would have worked as well
          .animate ({"left":"+=50px", "opacity":"0"}, 250, "swing", function() {
               eCCost.remove();
          });  
}
```

Comment: If my understanding is correct, only the eParent part of DOM is affected. Im 'adding' to the existing struction of eParent (#creditModule div).

Comment: No, he only does weird things with parentNodes etc. - his `eCCost` does point to the just created (outer) element, but he destroys it when resetting the innerHTML

Comment: Ive spent well over an hour thinking about the explanation you've written and I still cannot wrap my head around this.
As Im using '+=' to add the '#creditModule' div, how is it possible that the DOM is being reset?

(Also, please see comment posted under my question above).

Comment: I've added a link to an [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2305677/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

You are starting an animation and scheduling a timeout to work on DOM elements that will get modified in the middle of that operation if the user clicks quickly.  You have two options for fixing this:

1. Make the adding of new items upon a second click to be safe so that it doesn't mess up the previous animations.
2. Stop the previous animations and clean them up before starting a new one.

You can implement either behavior with the following rewrite and simplification of your code.  You control whether you get behavior #1 or #2 by whether you include the first line of code or not.

```
function creditCost(x) {
    // This first line of code is optional depending upon what you want to happen when the 
    // user clicks rapid fire.  With this line in place, any previous animations will
    // be stopped and their objects will be removed immediately
    // Without this line of code, previous objects will continue to animate and will then
    // clean remove themselves when the animation is done
    $("#creditModule .cCCost").stop(true, false).remove();

    // create HTML objects for cCCost
    var cCCost = $('<div class="cCCost"><p class="cCostNo">' + x + '</p></div>');
    // add these objects onto end of creditModule
    $("#creditModule").append(cCCost);

    cCCost
        .animate ({"left":"-=50px", "opacity":"1"}, 250, "swing")
        .delay(750)
        .animate({"left":"+=50px", "opacity":"0"}, 250, "swing", function () {
            cCCost.remove();
        });  
    }
})();
```

Note, I changed from `setTimeout()` to `.delay()` to make it easier to stop all future actions.  If you stayed with setTimeout(), then you would need to save the timerID returned from that so that you could call `clearTimeout()`.  Using `.delay()`, jQuery does this for us.

Comment: no, I don't think his problem is with the animations. He tries to animate different elements.

Comment: @Bergi - my initial explanation wasn't quite correct (I have since reworded), but I think the idea is right and the suggested code will work.

Comment: That code does not work - in the first line you remove a element (the `eCCost` variable) that does not exist at that moment

Comment: @Bergi - If the user is going fast, `eCCost` does exist at the time (because the previous animation and `setTimeout()` hasn't completed).  If it doesn't exist, then it is a harmless operation as the `$(eCCost)` will simply be empty and the method calls on it will do nothing.  So essentially what this code is doing is saying: "If the previous operation hasn't completed yet, then stop it and get rid of the `eCCost` object so we can start fresh with a new operation".

Comment: Ah, you've already changed it to a class selector - what I meant was that the local variable would have been undefined

Comment: Rewritten the core code to make it a lot simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @jfriend00, thanks for the explanation. I did do something similar (& a bit shorter I think). I inserted following line to remove previous instances but the resultant effect doesnt look nice:
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("cCCost").length > 0)
    {$(".cCCost").remove();}

Comment: @Kayote, just so you know - in jQuery, you don't have to check if there are any elements before calling a method.  You can just do `$(".cCCost").remove();`.  If there are no `.cCCost` items, then it just does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code for anyone who might want to do with mostly javascript. [Jsfiddle, excuse the CSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/ShCHD/2/)

```
function creditCost(x)
{
    var eParent = document.getElementById("creditModule");
    var eCCost = document.createElement("div");
    var eCostNo = document.createElement("p");
    var sCostNoTxt = document.createTextNode(x);
    eCCost.setAttribute("class","cCCost");
    eCostNo.setAttribute("class","cCostNo");
    eCostNo.appendChild(sCostNoTxt);
    eCCost.appendChild(eCostNo);
    eParent.insertBefore(eCCost, document.getElementById("creditSystem").nextSibling);
    $(eCCost).animate ({"left":"-=50px", "opacity":"1"}, 250, "swing");
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(eCCost).animate ({"left":"+=50px", "opacity":"0"}, 250, "swing", function ()
        {
            $(eCCost).remove();
        })  
    }, 1000);
}
```