# DOM injection without jquery

Tags: javascript, html, dom, code-injection

I am wondering how to inject HTML tags with DOM injection, without making use of the jquery library.

We want to generate several objects from an external javascript file, into the original page, but we don't want to be dependant on jquery (since it's 90kb) and we don't have control over the site which will use our script.

Comment: Do you want to inject them load-time or later on?

Comment: Great question. I see too many questions closed on here with casperOne's name on them. I came here form Google and got my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use

```
 object.innerHTML = "<br/><span>Text</span>"
```

Or use appendChild:

```
 var child = element.appendChild(child);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.appendChild

Both works.

Comment: Using `innerHTML` isn't really good practize! Use `appendChild` every time (if possible)! See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode

Answer (score 3):

Are you just looking for:

```
newNode = document.createElement(tagType);
```

and

```
parent.appendChild(newNode);
```

For more information about `document` level functions, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document

For methods that manipulate elements, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element

Answer (score 1):

If you have many elements to create and they are contained in a common root node, I suggest to create a `documentFragment` and append into it all the nodes you need to generate through `createElement()` and `appendChild()` methods

Then just append the `documentFragment` into the document

From MDN reference: [createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment)

> Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance