# javascript document.createElement or HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, createelement

I am confused on following style of writing code. I want to know which is the *practical* and *efficient* method to insert HTML tag in document.

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('demoId').innerHTML='<div>hello world and <a>click me</a> also</div>';
```

OR

```
var itd=document.createElement('div'),
    ita=document.createElement('a'),
    idt=document.createTextNode('hello world');
    iat=document.createTextNode('click me');
    idn=document.createTextNode('also');

    ita.appendChild(iat);
    itd.appendChild(idt);
    itd.appendChild(ita);
    itd.appendChild(idn)

    docuemtn.getElementById('demoId').appendChild(itd);
```

Which is the fastest and best method?

Comment: Why would you want to create html tags like this?

Comment: u can do a java script  profiling on Chrome to measure this

Comment: Everyone will probably say I'm crazy, but if you made this site and then I had to maintain it, I'd prefer you use option 1 and avoid option 2 for as long as possible. Also, I cannot imagine Option 2 ever being faster than option 1.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well just think about what each of them are doing. The first one is taking the string, parsing it and then calling `document.createElement`, `document.appendChild`, etc. (or similar methods) based on the output from the parsed string. The second is reducing the work load on the browser as you're stating directly what you want it to do.

[See a comparison on jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/adding-html-via-js)

According to jsPerf **option 1 is approximately 3 times slower than option 2**.

On the topic of maintainability option 1 is far easier to write but call me old fashioned, I'd prefer to use option 2 as it just feels much safer.

**Edit**

After a few results started coming in, the differing results piqued my curiosity. I ran the test twice with each of my browsers installed, Here is a screenshot of the results from jsPerf after all the tests  (operations/second, higher is better).

[image: jsPerf results]

So browsers seem to differ greatly in how they handle the two techniques. On average option 2 seems to be the faster due to Chrome and Safari's large gap favouring option 2. My conclusion is that we should just use whichever feels the most comfortable or fits best with your organisation's standards and not worry about which is more efficient.

The main thing this exercise has taught me is ***to not use IE10*** despite the great things I've heard about it.

Comment: It's pretty awesome :) second time I've used it.

Comment: I couldn't fathom why this was true, check out this post, it's very enlightening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode

Comment: Interesting, but in my browser (FF 19) innerHTML is faster (direct DOM manipulation is slower by 12% according to jsperf)

Comment: @tyriar , second one increases the file size, won't that make websiter heavier?

Comment: As in the amount of code increased the file size? That would make the tiniest of differences so small it couldn't be measured. If you're saying it will keep adding elements, it won't as I clear the div before every test (using innerHTML).

Comment: I'm on Chrome fyi, interesting results from Firefox 19 :P I guess it's more important which browser is being used.

Comment: IE11 is not even a tad faster here on my machine™