# Append HTML to div if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendchild

I need to check whether an element exists or not, and if it doesn't, then create it using `Jquery`.
For example, I have the following HTML code in my page:

```
<div class="g-array-item">
        <div class="g-array-item-image">Awesome Picture</div>
        <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>

<div class="g-array-item">
        <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>
```

I need `g-array-item-image` class div to be inside both `g-array-item` class divs.

This is what I tried so far without success:

```
if(jQuery(".g-array-item-image").length < 0 ){  
jQuery( '.g-array-item' ).append( jQuery( '<div class="g-array-item-image">123</div>' ) );
}
```

Desired result:

```
<div class="g-array-item">
        <div class="g-array-item-image">Awesome Picture</div>
        <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>

<div class="g-array-item">
        <div class="g-array-item-image">Awesome Picture</div>
        <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this can be done using bare javascript, see here a really nice reply to a previous question, it may help you achieve what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/15182437/982901

Comment: @user9459537 posted a answer you can check also code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the full code :

```
<div class="g-array-item">
        <div class="g-array-item-image">Awesome Picture</div>
        <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>

<div class="g-array-item">
        <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>


<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.g-array-item').each(function(){
        if($(this).find('.g-array-item-image').length == 0){
            $(this).prepend('<div class="g-array-item-image">123</div>');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You need here to use `prepend` instead of `append` otherwise it'll pop the image div after your item-something.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="g-array-item">
      <div class="g-array-item-image">Awesome Picture</div>
      <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
    </div>

    <div class="g-array-item">
      <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
    </div>
    <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".g-array-item").each(function() {
          if (!(jQuery(this).children('.g-array-item-image').hasClass('g-array-item-image'))) {
            jQuery(this).append('<div class="g-array-item-image">123</div>');
          }
        });
      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Simple way of doing this is each as below.

```
jQuery(".g-array-item").each(function() { 
      console.log(jQuery(this).children('.g-array-item-image').attr('class'));
      if (!(jQuery(this).children('.g-array-item-image').hasClass('g-array-item-image'))) {
        jQuery(this).append('<div class="g-array-item-image">123</div>');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It has a simple solution:

1. Check the element with class `g-array-item-image` on each element that has class `g-array-item`
2. If the element do not exist then the length for the element with class `g-array-item-image` will be `0` and you can `prepend()` it to get it at the top level inside div with class `g-array-item`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.g-array-item').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.g-array-item-image').length === 0){
      $(this).prepend('<div class="g-array-item-image">123</div>');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="g-array-item">
    <div class="g-array-item-image">Awesome Picture</div>
    <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>

<div class="g-array-item">
    <div class="g-array-item-somethingelse">Something else</div>
</div>
```