# Looping through images array and showing them to HTML page

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, loops

I'm facing issues with my JS code and I hope you guys can help me help me. All I want to do is loop 5 images stored in an array, and post them to my HTML page, basically.

JS:

```
function functieArray(){
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        imgArray[i];
    }
    document.getElementById("pozeGallery").innerHTML = imgArray.src;
};

var imgArray = new Array();
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'img/Gallery/poza0.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'img/Gallery/poza1.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'img/Gallery/poza2.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'img/Gallery/poza3.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'img/Gallery/poza4.jpg';
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick='functieArray()' class='galleryButons'>Category 1</button>
      <div id='pozeGallery'> </div>
```

Comment: You want to add all images to `#pozeGallery` element right?

Comment: Yes, I want to add all images to my page after I click a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually append them to the DOM for them to show up.

use the `appendChild()` method

In your case:

```js
function functieArray() {
    var gallery = document.getElementById("pozeGallery");
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        gallery.appendChild(imgArray[i]);
    }
};
```

Also note that in your code sample you are not calling `functieArray` anywhere so it might not work.

Comment: Alternatively, they could use `gallery.innerHTML += imgArray[i].outerHTML;`

Comment: that is really a bad practice, it means the browser has to rebuild the DOM everytime you change something, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode

Comment: Yes, in my answer I appended all the `outerHTML` first to a string and then set the `innerHTML` all at once. Another solution from the answer you cited is to use `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTML of the `Image` objects, use `Image#outerHTML`. Then you can just loop through the array adding to the gallery's `innerHTML`.

Here is how you should fix your code (I'm going to use a loop for creating the `Image` objects):

```js
var imgArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    imgArray[i] = new Image();
    imgArray[i].src = 'img/Gallery/poza' + i + '.jpg';
}

function functieArray() {
    var images = imgArray.map(img => img.outerHTML).join('');
    document.getElementById("pozeGallery").innerHTML = images;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='functieArray()' class='galleryButons'>Category 1</button>
<div id='pozeGallery'></div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer so that it isn't a duplicate of the others. Now it sets the `innerHTML` to the `outerHTML` of each `Image` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
function functieArray() {
    var gallery = document.getElementById("pozeGallery");
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        gallery.appendChild(imgArray[i]);
    }
};
var imgArray = new Array();
imgArray[0] = new Image();
imgArray[0].src = 'img/Gallery/poza0.jpg';

imgArray[1] = new Image();
imgArray[1].src = 'img/Gallery/poza1.jpg';

imgArray[2] = new Image();
imgArray[2].src = 'img/Gallery/poza2.jpg';

imgArray[3] = new Image();
imgArray[3].src = 'img/Gallery/poza3.jpg';

imgArray[4] = new Image();
imgArray[4].src = 'img/Gallery/poza4.jpg';
```

```html
<button onclick='functieArray()' class='galleryButons'>Category 1</button>
      <div id='pozeGallery'> </div>
```