# In Node/Javascript, how to load all images from directory and display

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

For this purpose, my approach is to read all image file names from a directory
and pass that as an array to the front-end javascript, which then reads one-by-one to
create a dynamic image elements.

**Step 1: node**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
//joining path of directory 
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'img');

const fileArray = [];
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //passsing directoryPath and callback function
  fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
    //handling error
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
    }

    //listing all files using forEach
    files.forEach(function(file) {
      console.log(file);
      fileArray.push(file);
    });
  });

  res.status(200).json({

    data: fileArray push // not sure, is this the way? 
  })
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {});
```

**Step 2:**
hence my front-end will look something like, where I need to loop over the recieved image files array.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var elem = document.createElement("img");
      elem.setAttribute("src", "images/hydrangeas.jpg");
      elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
      elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
      elem.setAttribute("alt", "Flower");
      document.getElementById("placehere").appendChild("elem");
   </script>
   <body>
      <div id="placehere">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**question** so how do I use the recieved array to form a dynamic img array in front-end?

Comment: Don't ask two things/topics in one question.

Comment: Just `res.status(200).json(fileArray)` is enough. However, "passing that to the fronend" is a little more complex. If your express app also serves the above frontend, you can easily put that image loop into a [view template](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). Otherwise you'll need ajax to load that JSON.

Comment: @ChrisG you miss that the result of `fs.readdir` is async.

Comment: Those are still two topics. The first part is the node code which does not work for you. And the second part is how to get it into your HTML which is a different topic.

Comment: @t.niese Right, but OP can just use the Sync version instead.

Comment: Why not just `.json(files)`? Why iterate `files`, push every element in a new array, and send the new array? That's just sending `files` with extra steps

Comment: thanks guys. so how would I use the incoming array to form the dynamic <img> array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36310296/looping-through-images-array-and-showing-them-to-html-page

Comment: @JeremyThille actually Im newbie, don't know how to get the array/files accessible in my index.html page so I can loop over them and create & append <img>to my <div>

Comment: Got it, I have posted a basic solution

Comment: Since this comes up again and again (and people don't use view engines at all or the abysmal ejs) I've created a repo showing how to show these images server-side and using ajax: https://github.com/khrismuc/express-images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and classic approach would be something like this :

Back-end :

```
import { promises } from "fs";

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const files = await promises.readdir(directoryPath);
        res.status(200).json(files);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
});
```

Front-end :

```
let files;
try{
    const response = await fetch("/");
    files = await response.json();
    // files is now an array of file names, do what you want with that (create <img> tags, etc.)
} catch(err){
    console.error(err)
}
```