# How to replace div child element?

Tags: javascript, html

On `async` call I am receiving a HTML component which I want to replace with another `div`.

Here is my main HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <H1>Name</h1>
  <div>Content wil reside here</div>
</div>
```

How can I replace div `id="main"`child with the `response.data` HTML response. Is there any possible way to do so?

Here is the async call:

```
axios.post(url, newState).then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  console.log(error.response.data);
});
```

It's returning me a complete `div`:

```
<div>
Hi
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be very aware when you use the dynamic html received from some response as it might not be safe.

Comment: You can refer to this question answer [How to replace div with another div in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347690/how-to-replace-div-with-another-div-in-javascript). **Warning**  Its work when you will know the `id` of the div which coming as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use jQuery to replace the element, using method replaceWith.
You can do it this way:

```
 axios.post(url,newState)
       .then(response => {
           const $recievedHTML = $(response.data);
           $("#main div").replaceWith($recievedHTML);
       })
```

This will work of course only if the received data is a valid HTML element.

Comment: Hi @Tomer Levitski thanks for the answer but is there a way to use only javascript with no jquery?

Comment: Of course! I think you should use innerHTML property

Answer (score -1):

`outerHTML` will replace the element itself.

JS

```
var main = document.getElementById('main');
axios.post(url,newState)
  .then(response => {
    main.outerHTML = response;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    main.outerHTML = error;
  });
```

HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: That will replace the *contents* of the div, not the div itself.

Comment: Try using `outerHTML` ^