# Create an Index in blogger alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I am trying to create an Index for my blog. I want to show a different page for different letters. For eg, In "Page A", I want to show all the labels starting with "A" ONLY. Then "Page B", "Page 0" etc.

I have figured out a code which gives out all the lists in the site:

```
function cat(json){ //get categories of blog & sort them
    var label = json.feed.category;
    var lst=[];

    for (i=0; i<label.length; i++){
          lst[i] = label[i].term ; 

      document.getElementById("listspan").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("listspan").innerHTML + "<a href=\"/search/label/" + label[i].term + "\">" + label[i].term + "</a><br>"  
     }
}

<span id="listspan"></span>
<script src="http://www.chordzone.org/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&max-results=0&callback=cat">
</script>
```

The issue that I'm facing is that the page crashes due to the large amount of labels.

Is there any way that I can reduce the load on the page, so that only labels starting with "A" or "B" etc., can be shown.
Is it possible to sort the labels alphabetically during the json call and show only the required labels, rather than calling all the labels in the site at once?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as `json.feed.category` is an Array.

```
.filter(function(category) {
  return category.term.toLowerCase().indexOf('a') === 0;
})
```

After filtered, all the item in that array is starting with "A", then insert those items into DOM. And using [appendChild](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) method is faster than [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) in this case. See this [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode).

```
.forEach(function(category) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = 'search/label/' + category.term;
  a.innerText = category.term;
  listspan.appendChild(a);
  listspan.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/77s6qfzc/1/)

Edit:

Copy the code below to a new HTML file, it works for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var cat = function(json) {
       var categories = json.feed.category;
       var lst = [];
       var listspan = document.createElement('span');
       listspan.id = 'listspan';

       categories
         // get the labels starting with "A" ONLY.
         .filter(function(category) {
           return category.term.toLowerCase().indexOf('a') === 0;
         })
         // not required
         .sort(function(a, b) {
           return +(a.term > b.term) || +(a.term === b.term) - 1;
         })
         // insert a tag to listspan, instead of using string, this way maybe more efficient.
         .forEach(function(category) {
           var a = document.createElement('a');
           a.href = 'search/label/' + category.term;
           a.innerText = category.term;
           listspan.appendChild(a);
           listspan.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
           lst.push(category.term);
         });

       // insert the list to DOM
       document.getElementById('container').appendChild(listspan);
      }
    </script>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="http://www.chordzone.org/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&max-results=0&callback=cat"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include this in my code and help me fix it? I'm pretty new to this so not sure how to include it.

Comment: Use [this](https://jsfiddle.net/77s6qfzc/2/), and replace your `cat` function with the `cat` function in JSFIDDLE. Also you need change HTML tag `<span id="listspan"></span>` to `<div id="container"></div>`, this will reduce DOM manipulation.

Comment: When I add the <script src="http://www.chordzone.org/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json&max-results=0&callback=cat">, it is not working. Can you please help me to fix it.

Comment: I edited my answer, you can copy and paste the code to a new HTML file then open the file in a browser, it should work.