# On deep water. add a div with js in a php printed line

Tags: javascript, php, html, printing

Maybe I'm way off, but here we go.

```
print '<li  '.$class.'><a id="flodet" href="index.php?artikelid='.$rad["id"].'">'.$rad["header"].'</a> </li>';
```

This line print links to articles from a database. The class `flodet` just style the link. What I want to do is to create another div inside the class `flodet`. I have tried to do this with these couple of lines of javascript.

```
function myFunc() {
    var bild = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById('flodet').appendChild(bild);
}
```

Am I way off or am I on the right track?

Comment: On the right track.

Comment: If you want it inside of the <li> tag you should do: document.getElementById('flodet').parentNode.appendChild(bild);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a snippet to play around with.

Few suggestions:

- `'<li  '.$class.'>` - this seems to be wrong ; use the attribute `class`
- You could select the `li` using `ul > li` if needed and can avoid setting class to each `li`; You could even decorate the parent `ul` with a `class` and select the `li`'s using `ul.myList li` where `myList` is the class of `ul`

```js
function myFunc() {
  /* To add a 'div' inside the list item anchor */
  /*
  var bild = document.createElement("div");
  bild.innerHTML = "My new DIV";
  document.getElementById('flodet').appendChild(bild);
  */
  
  /* To add a 'div' inside each list item */
  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var bild = document.createElement("div");
    bild.innerHTML = "My Div" + i;
    /* Add an attribute, say 'class' */
    bild.setAttribute("class", "divClass");
    listItems[i].appendChild(bild);
  }
}

window.onload = myFunc;
```

```css
/*  To select the list items */

ul > li {
  color: #DDD;
}

.divClass {
  border: 1px solid #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="flodet" href="">Link 1</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="flodet2" href="">Link 2</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="flodet3" href="">Link 3</a> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, just one question. class only get added on the first item in the list. Any idea why that is?

Comment: We could use it like `bild.setAttribute("class", "divClass");` to add an attribute to an element. `class only get added on the first item in the list` - is that in `PHP` code or `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely on the right track, but let me suggest one thing about your tiny code-piece:

I you are using styles to brush up the link, you are better of to set the `class`-attribute on the link rather than the id. ID's should be unique - That might not be the case, if there are more elements of this type generated by your code.

Comment: but then this line wouldn't work? document.getElementById('flodet').appendChild(bild);

Comment: No, then your code would require some change. Depending on what you exactly want to achieve, you can probably set different IDs or identify your elements by using `data-XY` attributes on them.

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById('flodet').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class='inline'> World!</div>");
```

```css
.inline {
 display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div id="flodet">Hello </div>
```

looks okay, add it inside a document.ready or something simular and you should be good to go.

I would suggest one change though,

Instead of

```
var bild = document.createElement("div");
    document.getElementById('flodet').appendChild(bild);
```

i would just do

```
document.getElementById('flodet').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div>Hello World!</div>");
```

Comment: I think what you suggest is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode

Comment: it works so it isn't wrong and it looks cleaner,  the difference is minimal for a small / medium size website.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, it's just worse, and he suggests the worse than the original better way from the author and that is wrong.

Comment: Again, the difference is minimal, close to none. But i'll update it to insertAdjacentHTML if it makes you happy :)

Comment: with innerHTML you can just put a + before the equal sign (=) and it adds instead of replaces.