# Deleting the last Element in a Div [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, html, dom, global-variables, getelementbyid

I'm having a strange problem. I'm trying to make a program that will add and delete div's inside another div called "body". To add divs, I use `document.getElementById("body").innerHTML`. Adding works fine. However, in the deleting function, I replace the "body" id with a variable with the id of the div that will be deleted. But when I run the code, I get the error "cannot set innerHTML of null". I tried to replace the id variable with a fixed local variable, and it worked fine. I also tried to add quotes to the variable but that didn't work either. Is there any reason why I can't set the id to a changing variable? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```js
var i = 1;

function myFunction() {
  var addDiv = document.getElementById("body2");
  addDiv.innerHTML += "<div id = '" + i + "'><br><textarea id = '1' > foo < /textarea></div > ";
  i++;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var deleteDiv = document.getElementById(i);
  deleteDiv.innerHTML = "";
  i--;
}
```

```html
<div id="body2">
  <div id="0">
    <textarea id="text">lol</textarea><button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just as an aside, document.getElementById("body").innerHTML can be shortened to document.body.innerHTML https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body

Comment: it is not really recommended to use raw numeric values as ids (which should be unique in the whole page). I recommend using a prefix, like `id = 'myprefix_"+i+"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are incrementing i after adding a div so you must use `i-1` while deleting to get correct id.

```js
var i = 1;

function myFunction() {
var addDiv = document.getElementById("body2");
addDiv.innerHTML += "<div id = '"+i+"'><br><textarea id = '1'>foo</textarea></div>";
i++;
}

function myFunction2() {
var deleteDiv = document.getElementById(i-1);
deleteDiv.remove();
i--;
}
```

```html
<div id = "body2">
<div id = "0">
   <textarea id = "text">lol</textarea><button onclick = 
   "myFunction()">Add</button>
    <button onclick = "myFunction2()">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but after adding and subtracting several times, it stops working and deletes them out of order.

Comment: that was because of `deleteDiv.innerHTML = "";`, I missed it earlier, you need to use  `deleteDiv.remove()` instead, i have updated code, seems to work now.

Answer (score 1):

To remove last child, you can even use CSS selector `last-child`. You should also add specific class to newly added divs as you would want to remove only newly added `div`s.

This will also remove dependency of `i`.

As an addon, you can also use `document.createElement` + `Node.appendChild` instead of setting `innerHTML`. `.innerHTMl` will be expensive for highly nested structure.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("body2").appendChild(getDiv());
}

function getDiv(i){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.classList.add('inner')
  var ta = document.createElement('textarea');
  ta.textContent = 'foo';
  div.appendChild(ta);
  return div;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var div = document.querySelector('#body2 div.inner:last-child')
  div && div.remove()
}
```

```html
<div id="body2">
  <div id="0">
    <textarea id="text">lol</textarea><button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
    <button onclick="myFunction2()">Delete</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can refer ["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) for more information.