# Image doesn't display inside innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wanting to get an image to display using innerHTML and I just can't seem to get it to work. It works fine with text and I'm trying to get it to display dynamically with other items inside innerHTML. Updated: the image is inside another element in the innerHTML. Image Example:

```js
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', "https://picsum.photos/200/300");/*sample pic*/
    div.innerHTML = '<a href="/"><h3>title</h3>'+ image + '</a>';
    document.getElementById('block').appendChild(div);/*work fine if appendChild(image) or text inside innerHTML*/
```

```html
<div id="block">
  image
</div>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` takes a string, not an `HTMLElement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way of adding an image would be via `appendChild()`, however to add an image element in the way you require, you'd need to specify the image in terms of its HTML tag and attributes as html, as follows:

```js
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    // Define the image tag and html directly and then apply to innerHTML in this way
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + "https://picsum.photos/200/300" + '" />';

    document.getElementById('block').appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="block">
  image
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

innerHtml is used to parse a string as HTML code.

To attach the image to the DOM element use:

```
div.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.appendChild()` on the image to make it a child of the div, instead of innerHTML:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', "https://picsum.photos/200/300");/*sample pic*/
    div.appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById('block').appendChild(div);/*work fine if appendChild(image) or text inside innerHTML*/
```

```html
<div id="block">
  image
</div>
```

See ["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) for the differences in the two

Answer (score 2):

Use this code instead of innerHTML

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute('src', "https://picsum.photos/200/300");/*sample pic*/
document.getElementById('block').appendChild(div).appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use appendChild instead of innerHTML:

```js
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var image = document.createElement('img');
    image.setAttribute('src', "https://picsum.photos/200/300");
    div.appendChild(image);
    document.getElementById('block').appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="block">
  image
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change this line
`div.innerHTML = image;`

To this:
`div.innerHTML = image.outerHTML;`

You're setting the innerHTML to an object currently instead of to html.