# Difference between adding HTML markup directly in JS and using document.create to add elements to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have found two different ways to add a span element to the DOM, but I am unsure which is better to use in terms of best practices and performance.

```
    const letterEl = document.createElement('span')
    letterEl.textContent = letter
    textEl.appendChild(letterEl)
```

OR

```
    textEl.innerHTML += '<span>' + letter + '</span>'
```

textEl is a h1 element that will hold the span 
letter is a string value

Comment: The second way is bad, because you're asking the browser DOM to do potentially much more work than it needs to. Remember, `e.innerHTML += "something"` is the same as `e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML + "something"`, so anything else that's inside the element gets re-added to the DOM when you do this. And DOM manipulation is usually the slowest part of any normal JS program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["innerHTML += ..." vs "appendChild(txtNode)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode)

Comment: setting `innerHTML` may result in XSS attack