# I need help! Basic javascript

Tags: javascript

so I'm trying to create a working comment section for a project. It doesn't need to be on bootstrap or still be there when refreshed, I just want to make it work. I feel like I'm close on figuring this out but there is something wrong on my code (as what the console log says). Please, I really need help :( Here's my javascript.

```
let commentSection = (event) => {
    let $addComment = document.querySelectorAll('.addComment')
    let $commentText = document.querySelectorAll('.comments')
    let $commentList = document.querySelectorAll('.commentList')
    let commentPost = commentText.value.trim();


    document.querySelectorAll('.commentList').innerHTML = `
    <li> Comment for the day: ${commentPost} </li>`
}

document.getElementById(`addComment`).addEventListener('click', commentSection);
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="comment" id="comment">
    <form>
        <label for="comment"></label>
        <textarea class="comments" placeholder="Let us know what you think!" name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
    </form>
    <button class="addComment" id="addComment"> COMMENT </button>
</div>
<div class="commList">
    <ul class="commentList" id="commentList"></ul>
</div>
```

console log on chrome says that there is something wrong on this part

```
let commentPost = commentText.value.trim();
```

I would appreciate any sort of help! Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question accordingly, it will make it easier to people to help you.

Comment: For starters please add what the console actually says

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `$`.
`let commentPost = $commentText.value.trim();`

Comment: Hi Elliot! It still not working :(

Comment: @spinHead It produces a different error, but it does solve one of the problems. Providing all the error messages involved makes it much easier for people to help.

Comment: Currently, console is not showing any errors whenever I hit the comment button, but it also doesn't create the comment

Answer (score 1):

You had some syntax errors and were not updating the list correctly:

```js
function commentSection(){
     let $addComment = document.querySelectorAll('.addComment')
     let $commentText = document.querySelectorAll('.comments')
     let $commentList = document.querySelectorAll('.commentList')
     let commentPost = $commentText[0].value.trim();
     if(commentPost){
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(commentPost));
          $commentList[0].appendChild(li);
      }
}
document.getElementById(`addComment`).addEventListener('click', commentSection);
```

```html
<form>
     <label for="comment"></label>
     <textarea class="comments" placeholder="Let us know what you think!" name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
</form>
<button class="addComment" id="addComment"> COMMENT </button>
<div class="commList">
     <ul class="commentList" id="commentList"></ul>
</div>
```

- Using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a a static NodeList object containing all the elements in the document that matches the specified selector. Therefore, since you aim to use only one element with this class name, you should reference the first element of this list.
- If you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode), you can see that `appendChild` does not cause a complete rebuild of the DOM or even all of the elements/nodes within the target. Whereas using `innerHTML` will cause a complete rebuild of the content of the target element, which if you're appending is unnecessary.

Comment: This is a good answer. You could improve upon it by adding more details about why your code works. Maybe an explanation that `querySelectorAll` returns an array and not a single element. And details about your use of `createElement` vs `innerHTML`.

Comment: I appreciate this!! I tried it but it didn't work too

Comment: @spinHead you can run the snippet and see for yourself that it works. Something else must be going wrong. And once again - "didn't work" is much less helpful than the actual error message.

Comment: @BrianThompson well noted!

Comment: @BrianThompson, you're right! It worked! Thank you so much

Comment: The reason I thought it wasnt working is that, it only works on one of the 12 other sections with the same element. I think I would have to make an array instead