# How do I destructure a json file to show all content in a site? There are thousands of objects and chrome crashes every time I load everything at once

Tags: javascript, json

There are thousands of objects and chrome crashes every time I load everything at once.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    event.preventDefault();

async function getData(){
    const response=await fetch(url)
    const data= await response.json();
    info(data)
}

getData();

function info(x){
    x.messages.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.creator.name+": "+element.text)
    // console.log(x.element.text)
    con.innerHTML += "<p>"+element.creator.name+": "+element.text+"</p>";
    });
}
```

This is the code im using rn

Comment: The obvious thing would be to introduce paging so that only a certain number of records from the dataset are fetched at any one time. An issue with your current code is that `innerHTML` concatenation re-parses the HTML each time which will have an effect on performance. You may want to `map` over the data to produce an array of HTML strings, and then use `innerHTML` once _after_ the iteration: `con.innerHTML = mappedHtml.join('')`, for example.

Comment: Maybe if you post (a little part of) the json it would be easier to help

Comment: `const  info = (x) => con.innerHTML = x.messages.map(element => 
\`${element.creator.name}: ${element.text}<br/>\`).join('');`
will work better since you are trusting innerHTML anyway

Comment: [`innerHtml +=` is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305654/innerhtml-vs-appendchildtxtnode) especially inside a loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to load one element per time using the appending child.
I leave here an alternative code.

#### [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-js-4jc8qh?file=/script.js)

> The API `https://dummyjson.com/products/1` test was used to get some dummy objects to be possible to get some information to test

#### The code

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("BtnInfo");
btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch("https://dummyjson.com/products/1");
    const data = await response.json();

    info(data);
  }

  getData();

  function info(x) {
    for (let key in x) {
      var pElement = document.createElement("p");
      pElement.textContent = `${key}: ${x[key]}`;
      document.body.appendChild(pElement);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
  <body>
    <button id="BtnInfo">Get API</button>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First innerhtml is slow because of parsing every time. Create a function to create Dom element and append it to the desired container. Adding paging or a flow to insert data in chunks can help too.

Comment: If you're doing iteration with DOM nodes you'll probably want to use a [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment).

Comment: True, fragment is faster, but both are much faster then innerhtml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).