# How do I make an infinite while loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, iteration, infinite-loop, do-while

So I wanted to make a simple effect of snowflakes falling from the sky randomly. I can make them all fall at the same time with different velocities, but i cant seem to call for a while loop again only for +1 snowflake. [Here is the link for the whole thing to give u an idea of what it should look like](https://codepen.io/Milos-Glamocak/pen/VwRrObK)

Here is the code:

```
function createSnowflakes() {
    let i = 0;
    while (i < 30) {
        document.body.innerHTML += `<div  class="snowflake${Math.floor(Math.random()*10)} snowflakes"></div>`;
        i++
    }
    let snowflakes = document.querySelectorAll('.snowflakes');

    snowflakes.forEach((snowflake) => {
        snowflake.style.transform = `translateX(${window.innerWidth * Math.random()}px)`;
        snowflake.style.animation = `falling1 ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)+3}s linear forwards`;
    })

    snowflakes.forEach((elem) => console.log(elem));
    snowflakes.forEach((elem) => {
        elem.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
            elem.remove();
            snowflakes = document.querySelectorAll('.snowflakes');
            if (snowflakes.length < 10) {
                createSnowflakes();
            }
        })
        
    })
}

createSnowflakes();
```

Comment: Why do you need an infinite loop? You already call `createSnowflakes()` again when it's time to do so (when there's less than 10 snowflakes left after removing them when the animation ends). All you might want to do is increase the numbers a bit, and make them appear more randomly (and in particular, at random times)

Comment: [Don't use `document.body.innerHTML +=`!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11515383/1048572) It [breaks your event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595808/1048572). Use [a proper alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2305654/1048572) instead!

Comment: @Bergi his code had an issue I fixed. Everytime snowflakes were made all of them were reset because of line 9

Comment: @KārlisKazāks Ah, yes, that as well, but the original approach should work fine without switching to `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `SetInterval()` read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval). Here's a basic implementation. I also improved readability by using `document.createElement` and `element.classList.add`

```
function createSnowflakes() {
    function create1Snowflake() {
      // document.body.innerHTML += `<div  class="snowflake${Math.floor(Math.random()*10)} snowflakes"></div>`;
      const snowflake = document.createElement("div")
      snowflake.classList.add(`snowflake${Math.floor(Math.random()*10)}`, "snowflakes")
      snowflake.style.transform = `translateX(${window.innerWidth * Math.random()}px)`;
      snowflake.style.animation = `falling1 ${Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)+3}s linear forwards`;

      snowflake.addEventListener('animationend', e => {
            snowflake.remove();
      })
      
      // add element to body
      document.body.appendChild(snowflake)
    }
    
  
    setInterval(() => {
      // make a snowflake
      create1Snowflake()
      
    }, 500)
}

createSnowflakes();
```

To change how fast the snowflakes appear change the 500 inside of `setInverval`, but remember that it takes milliseconds not seconds.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that thing with += on innerHTML... Also never knew what that appendChild does :D. Will make a research for the future.

Comment: Small note: `createElement` is not about readability, (`.innerHTML += xx` is technically more readable), but rather about performance. When you modify `innerHTML` (especially with `+=`), it means: the browser needs to (1) convert the DOM elements to an HTML string, (2) append some stuff to that string (3) parse and convert that string back to DOM elements. Plus, when you use `createElement`, you already get a reference to the elements - no need to search the DOM. BIG difference to performance.

Comment: @Christian never knew that! Thanks for explaining, but personally i always found it more readable too

Comment: You're welcome!

By the way, recreating the html with `innerHTML` also destroys any event handlers you might have set up, among other things. There may be cases where it makes sense though, for example when you want to completely overwrite/set an elements' children (it's faster than building an entire hierarchy with `createElement`).

Answer (score 1):

A naive infinite loop in javascript will typically cause the browser to lock up.
Additionally, it will not render correctly - it will look like it is skipping frames (since rendering is only done in the end). There is an API that makes that possible: [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). While it doesn't look like an infinite loop, that is what it does in practice (when you keep calling it).

**However,** looking at your code, you don't seem to need an infinite loop at all, but rather to trigger your snowmaker every few (milli)seconds - which can be done with [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

```js
function createSnowflakes() {
    ...
}

const handle = setInterval(createSnowflakes, 1000);
```

Notes:

1. `handle` is need if you want to stop the effect (just call `clearInterval(handle)`)
2. that will trigger every 1000ms (=1s)
3. if you want random/inconsistent timing, you should use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) instead:

   ```js
   let keepMakingThem = true;
   function createSnowflakes() {
       ...

       if (keepMakingEm) {
           setTimeout(Math.random() * 1000);
       }
   }
   createSnowFlakes();
   ```

   (in this case, setting `keepMakingThem` to false will break the loop and make it stop - **don't do that with `setInterval` though**)

Comment: Yea I also tried using setInterval with that but something was off when i did it... Can't even recreate it now :/... Although, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not look at the rest of the code. Kudos to the other people that did - the answers and comments there are quite useful.

That being said, if you need some advanced animations that you can't do with plain css, the approach I mentioned might help.